# How to fix type error with Keras Lambda layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I need to embed sentence universal encoder into my keras model using Google colab.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow import keras

def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    results = embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))["outputs"]
    return keras.backend.concatenate([results])

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
embed = hub.load(module_url)

input_size = 1
embed_size = 512

input_1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_size,), dtype=tf.string)

embed_layer = keras.layers.Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,))

x1 = embed_layer(input_1)
```

It throws a type error as follows.

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'outputs'
```

TF version: 2.3.0

Any hint to fix it is appreciated.

Comment: I have no knowledge about this, but i removed ["outputs"] and make `results`  as tensor and it works whitout any error. `results = embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))`

Comment: Great. Thanks. Just to mention it generates the following TF warning: "It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer."

Comment: Welcome. I am happy for helping.